# No adapter attached;recycler view skipping layout

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

so i am getting error in the `Recyclerview`.

activity_main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context=".MainActivity">

<!--edit text for entering the pin code-->
<EditText
android:id="@+id/idEdtPinCode"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_margin="5dp"
android:layout_toStartOf="@id/idBtnSearch"
android:layout_toLeftOf="@id/idBtnSearch"
android:hint="Enter PinCode"
android:inputType="number" />

<!--button for searchng the data-->
<Button
android:id="@+id/idBtnSearch"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
android:layout_margin="5dp"
android:background="@color/Purple_200"
android:text="Search"
android:textAllCaps="false" />

<!--progress bar for loading indicator-->
<ProgressBar
android:id="@+id/idPBLoading"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_centerInParent="true"
android:visibility="gone" />

<!--recycler view for displaying results in the form of list-->
<androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
 android:id="@+id/sessionsRV"
 android:layout_width="match_parent"
 android:layout_height="match_parent"
 android:layout_below="@id/idEdtPinCode"
  tools:listitem="@layout/center_rv_item" />



</RelativeLayout>
```

CenterRvmodel.kt

```
so this is my `CenterRvmodel`.kt file

package com.gtappdevelopers.finalvaac

data class CenterRvModel (
val sessionsName: String,

val sessionsAddress: String,

// string variable for center opening time.
val sessionsFromTime: String,

// string variable for center closing time.
val sessionsToTime: String,
var fee_type: String,

var ageLimit: Int,
var vaccineName: String,
var availableCapacity: Int)
```

center_rv_item.xml
so this my center_rv_item for lising `recyclerview`

<androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_margin="4dp">

```
<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <!--text view for displaying center name-->
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/idTVCenterName"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="3dp"
        android:drawableLeft="@drawable/ic_hospital"
        android:drawablePadding="4dp"
        android:padding="3dp"
        android:text="Center Name"
        android:textColor="@color/black" />

    <!--text view for displaying center address-->
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/idTVCenterAddress"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@id/idTVCenterName"
        android:layout_margin="3dp"
        android:drawableLeft="@drawable/ic_location"
        android:drawablePadding="4dp"
        android:padding="3dp"
        android:text="Center Address"
        android:textColor="@color/black" />

    <!--text view for displaying center timings-->
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/idTVCenterTimings"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@id/idTVCenterAddress"
        android:layout_margin="3dp"
        android:drawableLeft="@drawable/ic_time"
        android:drawablePadding="4dp"
        android:padding="3dp"
        android:text="Timings"
        android:textColor="@color/black" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/idLL1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@id/idTVCenterTimings"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:weightSum="2">

        <!--text view for displaying vaccine name-->
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/idTVVaccineName"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_margin="3dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:drawableLeft="@drawable/ic_vaccine"
            android:drawablePadding="4dp"
            android:padding="3dp"
            android:text="Vaccine Name"
            android:textColor="@color/black" />

        <!--text view for displaying center fees type-->
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/idTVFeeType"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:layout_margin="3dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:padding="3dp"
            android:text="Fee Type"
            android:textAlignment="center"
            android:textColor="@color/black" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/idLL2"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@id/idLL1"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:weightSum="2">

        <!--text view for displaying age limit-->
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/idTVAgeLimit"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:layout_margin="3dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:padding="3dp"
            android:text="Age Limit"
            android:textAlignment="center"
            android:textColor="@color/black" />


        <!--text view for displaying center availability-->
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/idTVAvaliablity"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:layout_margin="3dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:padding="3dp"
            android:text="Avaliablity"
            android:textAlignment="center"
            android:textColor="@color/black" />


    </LinearLayout>

</RelativeLayout>


</androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>
```

CenterRvAdapter.kt

```
package com.gtappdevelopers.finalvaac
import android.view.LayoutInflater
import android.view.View
import android.view.ViewGroup
import android.widget.TextView
import androidx.appcompat.view.menu.ActionMenuItemView
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView

// on below line we are creating our adapter class
// in this class we are passing our array list
// and our View Holder class which we have created.
class CenterRvAdapter(private val firebaseKotlinVersion:List 
<CenterRvModel>):RecyclerView.Adapter<CenterRvAdapter.CenterRVViewHolder>() {
class CenterRVViewHolder(itemView: View) : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(itemView) {
    val centerNameTV: TextView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.idTVCenterName)
    val centerAddressTV: TextView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.idTVCenterAddress)
    val centerTimings: TextView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.idTVCenterTimings)
    val vaccineNameTV: TextView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.idTVVaccineName)
    val centerAgeLimitTV: TextView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.idTVAgeLimit)
    val centerFeeTypeTV: TextView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.idTVFeeType)
    val avalabilityTV: TextView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.idTVAvaliablity)

}

// below method is for on Create Vew Holder.
override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): CenterRVViewHolder {
    // this method is use to inflate the layout file
    // which we have created for our recycler view.
    // on below line we are inflating our layout file.
    val itemView = LayoutInflater.from(parent.context).inflate(R.layout.center_rv_item, 
   parent, false)
    

    // at last we are returning our view holder
    // class with our item View File.
    return CenterRVViewHolder(itemView)

}

// this method is to count the size of our array list.


// below method is to set the data to each view of our recycler view item.
override fun onBindViewHolder(holder:CenterRVViewHolder, position: Int) {

    // on below line we are getting item
    // from our list along with its position.
    val currentItem = firebaseKotlinVersion[position]

    // after getting current item we are setting
    // data from our list to our text views.
    holder.centerNameTV.text = currentItem.sessionsName
    holder.centerAddressTV.text = currentItem.sessionsAddress
    holder.centerTimings.text = ("From :" + currentItem.sessionsFromTime + " To : " + 
   currentItem.sessionsToTime)
    holder.vaccineNameTV.text = currentItem.vaccineName
    holder.centerAgeLimitTV.text = "Age Limit :" + currentItem.ageLimit.toString()
    holder.centerFeeTypeTV.text = currentItem.fee_type
    holder.avalabilityTV.text = "Availability :" + currentItem.availableCapacity.toString()

}
override fun getItemCount(): Int {

    // on below line we are returning
    // the size of our array list.
    return firebaseKotlinVersion.size
 }
}
```

mainactivity.kt

```
package com.gtappdevelopers.finalvaac
import android.app.DatePickerDialog
 import android.os.Bundle
 import android.util.Log
import android.view.View
import android.widget.Button
import android.widget.EditText
import android.widget.ProgressBar
import android.widget.Toast
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity
 import androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
import com.android.volley.Request
import com.android.volley.toolbox.JsonObjectRequest
import com.android.volley.toolbox.Volley
import org.json.JSONException
 import java.util.*
import kotlin.collections.ArrayList


class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

// creating a variable for our button.
 lateinit var searchButton: Button

// creating variable for our edit text.
lateinit var pinCodeEdt: EditText

// creating a variable for our recycler view.
lateinit var sessionsRV: RecyclerView

// creating a variable for adapter class.
lateinit var CenterRvAdapter: CenterRvAdapter

// creating a variable for our list
lateinit var centerList: List<CenterRvModel>

// creating a variable for progress bar.
 lateinit var loadingPB: ProgressBar

  override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

    // inside on create method we are initializing
    // all our variables which we have declared.
    searchButton = findViewById(R.id.idBtnSearch)
    pinCodeEdt = findViewById(R.id.idEdtPinCode)
    sessionsRV = findViewById(R.id.sessionsRV)
    loadingPB = findViewById(R.id.idPBLoading)
    centerList = ArrayList <CenterRvModel>()

    // on below line we are adding on
    // click listener to our button.
    searchButton.setOnClickListener {

        // inside on click listener we are getting data from
        // edit text and creating a val for ite on below line.
        val pinCode = pinCodeEdt.text.toString()

        // on below line we are validating
        // our pin code as 6 digit or not.
         if (pinCode.length != 6) {

            // this method is called when users enter invalid pin code.
            Toast.makeText(this@MainActivity, "Please enter valid pin code", 
    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
        } else {

            // if the pincode is correct.
            // first of all we are clearing our array list this
            // will clear the data in it if already present.
            (centerList as ArrayList<CenterRvModel>).clear()

            // on below line we are getting instance of our calendar.
            val c = Calendar.getInstance()

            // on below line we are getting our current year, month and day.
            val year = c.get(Calendar.YEAR)
            val month = c.get(Calendar.MONTH)
            val day = c.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH)

            // on below line we are creating our date picker dialog.
            val dpd = DatePickerDialog(this,
                DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener { view, year, monthOfYear, dayOfMonth ->
                    loadingPB.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE)

                    // on below line we are creating a date string for our date
                    val dateStr: String = """$dayOfMonth - ${monthOfYear + 1} - $year"""

                    // on below line we are calling a method to get
                    // the appointment info for vaccination centers
                    // and we are passing our pin code to it.
                    getAppointments(pinCode, dateStr)
                },
                year,
                month,
                day
            )
            // calling a method to display
            // our datepicker dialog.
            dpd.show()
        }
    }
    }

    // below is the method for getting data from API.
    private fun getAppointments(pinCode: String, date: String) {
    val url = "https://cdn-api.co-vin.in/api/v2/appointment/sessions/public/findByPin? 
   pincode="+pinCode+"&date="+date
    val queue = Volley.newRequestQueue(this@MainActivity)
    val request = JsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.GET, url, null, { response ->
            // this method is called when we get successful response from API.

            // we are setting the visibility of progress bar as gone.
            loadingPB.setVisibility(View.GONE)
            // on below line we are adding a try catch block.
            try {
                // in try block we are creating a variable for center
                // array and getting our array from our object.
                val centerArray = response.getJSONArray("sessions")

                // on below line we are checking if the length of the array is 0.
                // the zero length indicates that there is no data for the given pincode.
                if (centerArray.length().equals(0)) {
                    Toast.makeText(this, "No center Found", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
                }
                for (i in 0 until centerArray.length()) {

                    // on below line we are creating a variable for our center object.
                    val sessionsObj = centerArray.getJSONObject(0)


                    // on below line we are getting data from our session
                    // object and we are storing that in a different variable.
                    val sessionsName: String = sessionsObj.getString("name")
                    val sessionsAddress: String = sessionsObj.getString("address")
                    val sessionsFromTime: String = sessionsObj.getString("from")
                    val sessionsToTime: String = sessionsObj.getString("to")
                    val fee_type: String = sessionsObj.getString("fee_type")

                    // on below line we are creating a variable for our session object
                    val sessionObj = sessionsObj.getJSONArray("sessions").getJSONObject(0)
                    val ageLimit: Int = sessionObj.getInt("min_age_limit")
                    val vaccineName: String = sessionObj.getString("vaccine")
                    val avaliableCapacity: Int = sessionObj.getInt("available_capacity")

                    // after extracting all the data we are passing this
                    // data to our modal class we have created
                    // a variable for it as center.
                    val center = CenterRvModel(
                        sessionsName,
                        sessionsAddress,
                        sessionsFromTime,
                        sessionsToTime,
                        fee_type,
                        ageLimit,
                        vaccineName,
                        avaliableCapacity
                    )
                    // after that we are passing this modal to our list on the below line.
                    centerList=centerList+center
                }

                // on the below line we are passing this list to our adapter class.
                CenterRvAdapter = CenterRvAdapter(centerList)

                // on the below line we are setting layout manager to our recycler view.
                LinearLayoutManager(this).also { it.also { this.sessionsRV.layoutManager = it 
         } }

                // on the below line we are setting an adapter to our recycler view.
                CenterRvAdapter.also { sessionsRV.adapter = it }

                // on the below line we are notifying our adapter as the data is updated.

                this.CenterRvAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged()
            } catch (e: JSONException) {
                // below line is for handling json exception.
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        },
            { error ->
                // this method is called when we get any
                // error while fetching data from our API
                Log.e("TAG", "RESPONSE IS $error")
                // in this case we are simply displaying a toast message.
                Toast.makeText(this@MainActivity, "Fail to get response", 
    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
            })
    // at last we are adding
    // our request to our queue.
    queue.add(request)
 }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

1. Pass i instead of 0

   val sessionsObj = centerArray.getJSONObject(0)
   val sessionObj = sessionsObj.getJSONArray("sessions").getJSONObject(0)

It looks like you are mixing up with the variable name with actual Adapter name - CenterRvAdapter.
So consider renaming your variable `CenterRvAdapter` to something different like `centerRvAdapter` or just `adapter` and while doing that, make sure you accidentally not leave that class name except where the variable is initialized.

Comment: can u tell how to create setadapter

Answer (score 0):

That error occurs when the adapter is not attached to recycler-view.

- You can setadpter to recycler view with an empty list. That error will not occur. then add data later and notify it.
- OR IN YOUR CODE Where you wrote this

  ```
  // on the below line we are setting an adapter to our recycler view.
  CenterRvAdapter.also { sessionsRV.adapter = it }

  // on the below line we are notifying our adapter as the data is updated.

  this.CenterRvAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged()
  ```

Replace with this code. Notify in a UI thread as you cannot access UI element in background threads. Remember to check the logs to tell it is executed or not.

```
   activity?.runOnUiThread {
        Log.d("TAG", "runOnUiThread IS CALLED ")
        sessionsRV.adapter = CenterRvAdapter
        CenterRvAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged()

    }
```

Comment: can u tell how to setadpater to recyclerview plzzzz

Comment: this is setadapter in kotlin 
sessionsRV.adapter = CenterRvAdapter

during oncreate the adapter was not attached. Which is not the main issue. you can attach adapter with an empty list

if list was null return 0 here

override fun getItemCount(): Int {

    // on below line we are returning
    // the size of our array list.
    return firebaseKotlinVersion.size
 }